# How do I prove that if T is a fintype, finset T is a fintype as well?

Tags: types

I would like to prove this

```
definition fintype_of_finset [instance] {T : Type} [HfT : fintype T] : fintype (finset T)
```

I don't know where to start.

Comment: Surely you should start by applying the `fintype` constructor? `HfT` gives you a list of all `T`, with which you get a `finset (finset T)` via `finset.list_powerset` (found using `find_decl`). At that point you'll likely have to go classical in order to extract a `list (finset A)` out of the quotient.

Comment: This sounds a bit like a homework question